# convoluted C++11 template specialization code: can it be written in a simpler way?

Tags: c++11, template-specialization

I'm using C++11 to develop a somewhat generic pipeline framework.
For that, I defined:

- a DataBuffer class with reference counting.
- a Producer class which takes a certain input type "IN" and generate a certain output type "OUT"

I want to make sure that the framework transparently updates the DataBuffer reference count so the programmer doesn't need to take care of it.
Here's what I came up with (works fine apparently):

```
template <class T>
class DataBuffer
{
  public:
    void   Acquire() {}
    void   Release() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct is_databuffer_ptr { static constexpr bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct is_databuffer_ptr<DataBuffer<T>* > { static constexpr bool value = true; };

template<typename T>
struct is_databuffer_ref { static constexpr bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct is_databuffer_ref<DataBuffer<T>& > { static constexpr bool value = true; };

template<typename T>
struct is_databuffer { static constexpr bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct is_databuffer<DataBuffer<T> > { static constexpr bool value = true; };

template <class IN, class OUT>
class Producer
{
  public:
    template< typename T=OUT
            , typename std::enable_if<  !is_databuffer_ptr<T>::value
                                     && !is_databuffer_ref<T>::value
                                     && !is_databuffer<T>::value    >::type* = nullptr>
    void  Produce(const OUT& result)
    { std::cout << "produce (default)\n"; }

    template< typename T=OUT
            , typename std::enable_if<is_databuffer_ptr<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    void  Produce(OUT databuf)
    {
      std::cout << "produce (databuf ptr)\n";
      databuf->Release();
    }

    template< typename T=OUT
            , typename std::enable_if<  is_databuffer_ref<T>::value
                                     || is_databuffer<T>::value    >::type* = nullptr>
    void  Produce(OUT& databuf)
    {
      std::cout << "produce (databuf ref)\n";
      databuf.Release();
    }
};
```

Now I'm looking at the code and find it quite convoluted.

Here's my question: is there a simpler way to write this in C++11?

Comment: You are looking for a [codereview.se]. You would better be served on that site.

Comment: Also, just an FYI: C++14 defines `enable_if_t` and C++11 includes `std::true_type and std::false_type`. Both combined would dramatically simplify this code.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, well, I guess there is no better way to do this without switching to C++14 and later, so I guess I'll accept your answer

Comment: @Rakete1111, thanks for point to this